# Jquery Mobile multi page Link works on second click only

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Hi i am newbie in jquery mobile development. I have a index.html page (normal page) which has link to inner page i.e. page2.html (which is multi page template). The problem is links present in this page works on second click only. Can you please help me on this?

```
rel="external" href="#Ans1" style="text-decoration:none">Link 1
```

&&

```
data-ajax="false" href="#Ans1" style="text-decoration:none">Link 2
```

i tried the above two methods.

Comment: Missing some bits of code here...

Comment: the entire code is here...

Comment: <div data-role="content">
     <div>
         <p><a data-ajax="false" href="#Ans1" style="text-decoration:none">1. Link 1</a></p>
  
   <p><a data-ajax="false" href="#Ans2" style="text-decoration:none">2. Link 2</a></p>
  
   
  </div>        
        
 </div><!-- /content -->